# Dart: doesn't override generic method has generic parameter type similar to the return type

Tags: flutter, dart, generic-method

I have an issue to override a generic method from an abstract class.

Here is my abstract class:

```
abstract class A {
  String getData<Type>(Type key);
}
```

when I created a class (B) to implement class (A) as showing below:

```
class B implements A {
  @override
  String getData<String>(String key) {     //Error <= B.getData' ('String Function<String>(String)') isn't a valid override of 'A.getData' ('String Function<Type>(Type)')

    return "";
  }
}
```

Shown the below compilation error at (getData) method:

> 'B.getData' ('String Function(String)') isn't a valid override of 'A.getData' ('String Function(Type)'). dart(invalid_override)

And this error at the return statement:

> A value of type 'String can't be returned from method 'getData' because it has a return type of 'String'.

It's confusing for me why I am getting this error related to the override when the generic type similar to return type. as when I created another class (C) with `getData<int>(int key)` instead of `getData<String>(String key)` everything works as expected:

```
class C implements A {
  @override
  String getData<int>(int key) {

    return "";
  }
}
```

Also with the class (B) if I deleted the return type as shown below everything will work as expected:

```
class B implements A {

  @override
  getData<String>(String key) {

     return "";
  }
}
```

Is it an issue in Dart design so I can be aware of it because this behavior does not exist in c# language for example?

**DartPad Link:**
https://dartpad.dev/ebc7e6361d0cf1c6afad2f52ab8ebcaa

Comment: This is a very interesting one. I highly recommend you to share that in the dart lang repository on GitHub: https://github.com/dart-lang/language

Comment: Can you update the question with a DartPad full code, please? Like what's showing here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40719

Answer (score 2):

The first method you wrote is generic over a type parameter named `Type`, and has return type `String`.  That is, it is the function which for any type `Type` returns something of type `String`.

The second method, is generic over a type parameter named `String`, and returns something of the type parameter type.  The fact that the type parameter is **named** `String` makes it look like you have the same return type in the first method and the second, but you don't.  The first method has a return to of `String`.  The second method has a return type of "the type variable that was just introduced and has name `String`".  Those two types are unrelated, and so the override is invalid.  If you rename the type variable in the second method to `T`, you get the following equivalent method:

```
class B implements A {
  @override
  T getData<T>(T key) {
    return "";
  }
}
```

and it should now be clear why your override is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have attached a DartPad link with the code
Even if I changed "Type" to "T", I'll get the same error.

Comment: Thanks, It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The method signature

```
String getData<Type>(Type key);
```

Would more typically be written with a `T` instead of `Type`, since `Type` [already has a meaning](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Type-class.html).

```
String getData<T>(T key);
```

This signature is for a method that allows any type to be filled in for `T`. This means that *every* subclass must have a method that allows for *any* type `T`.

I suspect that what you want is for subclasses to be specialized to a single generic type - in that case you want to move the generic from the method level to the class level.

```
abstract class A<T> {
  String getData(T key);
}

class B implements A<String> {
  @override
  String getData(String key) => '';
}

class C implements A<int> {
  @override
  String getData(int key) => '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have attached a DartPad link with the code
I don't want to move the generic from the method level to the class level.
The idea of my question here is I suspect there is something wrong in Dart's design to override a generic method that has the same type of return type.

I tried your solution the I had another, I'll log it later

Comment: See Leaf's answer. When you write `String getData<String>(String key)` is is the same as writing `T getData<T>(T key)`. You can't have "String" mean _both_ the type `String`  in the return type _and_ the generic type argument `String`. Using `<String>` and `<int>` as generic type arguments is _very_ unusual. You almost certainly don't want to create a generic argument with the name of a very common type, and you _can't_ do it if you want to return that type. The workaround is to `import 'dart:core' as core;` and `core.String getData<String>(String key)`.

Comment: See also https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-generic-methods

Comment: Thanks @Nata-Bosch, I am able to fix it with the workaround you mentioned, Leaf's answer makes sense for me now